# Limit the array list in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I would like  to know how i limit a comments list(array) or a table list.

Because i´m making a web site and users can make posts and comments but i want limit it by page.
Because if not it goes to infinite.

How i do that, for comments and posts(the posts are in a table)??

I´m using php by the way.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You'd have to supply a little more information, like what you're doing that needs limiting...some code perhaps?

Comment: LIMIT = X in your SQL? It all depends on your code. Show some.

Answer (score 3):

You'll largely be relying on the LIMIT clause of your query. This will let you return a fixed number of results, starting from any index. So the first  ten records could be returned with:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM comments WHERE post_id = 5 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Note, the `0` is not required, but it makes the next example easier to understand.

The second 10 could be returned with:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM comments WHERE post_id = 5 LIMIT 11, 10
```

Typically you're store a `$page` variable in the URL and perform a bit of math against this, and the total number of comments per page to determine what your offset should be.

Comment: i have code but i don´t know how to put it here!

Comment: Click the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10609885/edit) and paste in your code. You must include four spaces before each line to format it as code.